# Understanding benchmark scores - i7-11390H vs i7-1195G7

Tags: laptop, processor, intel

I am shopping for my first new laptop since 2013, and trying to estimate the performance I will experience.

Two models I am considering (*HP Spectre x360* 16" & *MSI Summit* 16") have the **i7-11390H** and the **i7-1195G7**, respectively. I know that in general the H series is "higher end." I would like to know more about what that actually means. When I look at the benchmarks on [CPUBenchmark.net](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-i7-11390H-vs-Intel-i7-1195G7/4619vs4514), the two processors score almost identically. I asked on a redditt sub devoted to one of the machines I am comparing and was told that the 11390H is "technically superior." I asked what technically superior means and was told that the maximum power usage is higher on the 11390H. That seems to me like it would make the 1195G7 better - achieving the same performance with less power consumption.

I can believe that there is more to the story that what appears on CPUBenchmarks, but what is it?

[image: CPU Spec Comparison]

[image: CPU Mark Rating Comparison]

[image: CPU Single Thread Comparison]

https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/Intel-i7-11390H-vs-Intel-i7-1195G7/4619vs4514

Answer (score 2):

For laptop cpu's, don't compare the cpu speed on some random benchmark site. Laptop CPU's are always limited by cooling and vrm, two values Intel/AMD have no control over. Try asking your local computer store which is best for your needs.

And about that H vs G7, that H means Intel positioned it for laptops with better cooling and vrm, so it should indeed preform better than the G7. Still, the G7 can have better cooling/vrm and then will preform better. This all depends on the specific laptop model and I cannot say much about that